# angularjs how to show progress bar while repeater is filtering

Tags: angularjs, filter, progress-bar, repeater

I have quite a large table that is created by ng-repeater, I have been trying to create a progress linear for it while it is filtering but I can't seem to get the directive right.
HTML

```
<div id="myProgress" ng-show="angularIsWorking">
        <md-progress-linear md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-linear>
    </div>

        <tr ng-repeat="msg in (filteredItems = (midList | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter: searchFilter | filter: searchByText | limitTo: intMaxMsgs))" ng-class-odd="'trMessagesBlue'" ng-class-even="'trMessagesBright'" my-repeat-directive>
```

angularjs

```
myapp.directive('myRepeatDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (scope.$first) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.angularIsWorking = true;
                }, 0)
            }
            else (scope.$last) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.angularIsWorking = false;
                }, 0)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My directive runs at the correct times but the problem is that I can't access my full scope since it is in the repeater, I only get item data passed, no other variables within my scope can't be controlled from this directive.

I tried appending myProgressBar through the directive but then it wouldn't work, so it needs to be on the page when it loads.

I hope there is not an awful lot that I am doing wrong, please help because I can't seem to find one example that works while repeater is filtering. Everybody else just has progress show up when switching routes.

I have also noticed that this would slow down my filtering even more, so maybe I should not make this feature, I just wanted an indicator while lazy loading more msgs into my table

Thank you

Comment: you can use `$.watch`